# Firefox jQuery and jQuery UI validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Does anyone know if there is a option buried in Firefox to turn off validation per specific file? I like to use the Web Developer Toolbar to alert me if I have errors in my own javascript and css but when I use jQuery and the jQuery UI libraries it always gives me an error. I know that these are made to be cross browser compatible and will not validate but using these defeats the purpose of using the Web Developer toolbar. I have looked through all the options and can't seem to find anything.

Or does someone know of another nice add-in that will do what I want?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: So, you are saying that the browser is displaying a javascript error in jQuery and jQuery UI libraries? if so, try downloading the latest libs and try again. If the problem still presists, then there has to be something wrong with your code that is using the libs not with jQuery itself.

Comment: Yes I am receiving errors on both the javascript and css for jQuery and jQuery UI. I am loading from the CDN and have tried different versions. There are errors for jQuery like "missing ;" and in the jQuery UI css there are a bunch of "Deceleration Dropped" which are just warnings but I have to sift through them to check if it is my code or not. If I create just a minimal page that only loads the jQuery and jQuery UI libraries I get the same errors and warnings. I have had this problem with Firefox for some time now and on different OS's